# How to avoid double square brackets under JSON Array while retriving data from MAP

Tags: java

I am storing data inside a LinkedHaspMap in form of String as key and JSONArray as its value 
But while retrieving data from the Map , i am getting double square brackets for value

This is my code

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<String, JsonArray> datafromdb = new LinkedHashMap<String, JsonArray>();
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            JsonArray jsonarray = new JsonArray();
            JsonObject pacs_obj = new JsonObject();
            pacs_obj.addProperty("pac_id", "1235");
            jsonarray.add(pacs_obj);
            String new_catid = "1";

            if (!datafromdb.containsKey(new_catid)) {
                datafromdb.put(new_catid, new JsonArray());
            }
            datafromdb.get(new_catid).add(jsonarray);
        }
        Iterator it = datafromdb.entrySet().iterator();
        JsonArray catarr = new JsonArray();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            JsonArray array = (JsonArray) pair.getValue();
            System.out.println(array);
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is

```
[[{"pac_id":"1235"}],[{"pac_id":"1235"}]]
```

Where as the output must be

```
[{"pac_id":"1235"},{"pac_id":"1235"}]
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this issue

Comment: simply use this `datafromdb.put(new_catid, jsonarray);` , remove `if` code

Comment: This is why you shouldn't play with `Json*` elements but with actual types!

Comment: @PavneetSingh if i do so it will not add other elements

Comment: you should update your question , mentioning the answer in linked duplicate didn't solve your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if key is not there at first time then your are adding an empty `JSONArray` and later you are fetching that empty array and adding your created array in it.

if the key is there then fetch the already created array and add new array in it.

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    JsonArray jsonarray = new JsonArray();
    JsonObject pacs_obj = new JsonObject();
    pacs_obj.addProperty("pac_id", "1235");
    jsonarray.add(pacs_obj);
    String new_catid = "1";

    if (datafromdb.containsKey(new_catid)) {
        datafromdb.get(new_catid).add(jsonarray);
    }
    else{
        datafromdb.put(new_catid, jsonarray);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but  if i do so it will not add other elements –

Comment: @Pawan wait , let me modify for duplicates

Comment: @Pawan check the update , it's done

Comment: thanks a lot , its great .

Comment: @Pawan i am glad that i could help, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `datafromdb` Map is `Map<String, JsonArray>`. The Map is the outer array that you wish to keep, the `JsonArray` is the inner array that is unnecessary. To get rid of the inner array use `JsonObject` instead of `JsonArray`.

```
 Map<String, JsonObject> datafromdb = new LinkedHashMap<>();
 for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
     JsonObject pacs_obj = new JsonObject();
     pacs_obj.addProperty("pac_id", "1235");
     String new_catid = "1";

     if (!datafromdb.containsKey(new_catid)) {
         datafromdb.put(new_catid, new JsonObject());
     }
     datafromdb.get(new_catid).add(pacs_obj);
 }
 Iterator it = datafromdb.entrySet().iterator();
 while (it.hasNext()) {
     Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
     JsonObject object = (JsonObject) pair.getValue();
     System.out.println(object);
 }
```

Comment: your answer works no doubts but it will replace an empty jsonarray `[]` with an empty jsonobject  `{}` which is un-necessary overhead, rest it's upto the requirement/decision of OP about the representation

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your example is not your real code and it is just a small example to create a populated Map to reproduce the output:

From a map of arrays you can create a single array just concatenating all of them:

```
Iterator it = datafromdb.entrySet().iterator();
JsonArray catarr = new JsonArray();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
    JsonArray array = (JsonArray) pair.getValue();
    for (int i=0;i<array.size();i++) {
        JsonArray inner=(JsonArray)array.get(i);
        catarr.addAll(inner);
    }
}
System.out.println(catarr);
```